# Loading an HTML file into a UIWebView using ParseConfig from Parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, parse-platform

I am currently trying to load an `html` file into a `UIWebView` via `ParseConfig`. As of now I am loading the file locally within the app, but I want to be able to update the content of the `html` file without having to submit for an Apple update each time. I was wondering if anyone had an experience loading files from `ParseConfig`? I have included a block of code that I am currently using to load a `URL` as a String from `ParseConfig` that works perfectly. I have also included the code I use now to load the `html` file locally.

**Code for loading URL as String from ParseConfig**

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{

    super.viewDidLoad()

    PFConfig.getConfigInBackgroundWithBlock
        {
        (config: PFConfig!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        let menu = config["menuLink"] as String
            NSLog("Yay! The number is %@!", menu)

            let requestURL = NSURL(string: menu)

            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)

            self.webView.loadRequest(request)
        }
}
```

**Code used for loading html file locally**

```
func loadURL()
{

    var requestURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("contact_your_ra", ofType: "html")!)

   let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
   webView.loadRequest(request)
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have loaded an HTML file stored in ParseConfig with no trouble at all. Simple store your HTML file as a string value in the Parse Config table, then load that file into the UIWebView using that loads via `loadHTMLString`

Something like this:

```
PFConfig *config = [PFConfig currentConfig];
NSString *htmlString = [config objectForKey:@"htmlString"];
[webView loadHTMLString: htmlString baseURL: nil];
```

Comment: Do you mean load the html file from a website? Right now the file isn't hosted on a site yet.

Comment: Thanks! Worked awesome!